# A line-break in a <select> menu when page width decreases

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, menu, line-breaks

I have a `select` menu on a responsive page, which is set with a fluid width (% value). Everything looks fine until i decrease the page size, when the default value of the `select` menu (i.e when it's not focussed or clicked on) becomes squashed in the container and overflows, causing part of the text to be hidden, like [this](http://f.cl.ly/items/1H0W3P14212N2Q0k3H3G/Screen%20Shot%202012-09-09%20at%2016.38.36.png). Ideally, this needs to be solved.

I was thinking of incoporarting a line-break, using CSS/Javascript whenever the text overflows. However, I can not think of an appropriate CSS property or JS method to do this on a `select` element. Does anyone have experience with this or know how to solve it? You don't need to use my suggestion, feel free to come up with something else. The main thing is the text needs to be shown in it's entirety all the time on any screen size.

I have a jsfiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/69Ctv/), which uses CSS animations to simulate the page size decreasing.

Comment: `SELECT` element (a *Combobox*) can only display one line by design, including those on each selection entry. If `min-width` style is not acceptable, then you'll need to create your own *combobox* interface.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information - that's what I thought :)